# Flyway creates flyway_schema_history but not entity table

Tags: java, spring-boot

My aim is to migrate User entity to mysql database with the following configuration.

When I **mvn spring-boot:run**, I can see **flyway_schema_history** table in DB, but not the entity related table. What am I missing?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
flyway.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
flyway.user = root
flyway.password = root
```

Here's my User entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "password")
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    boolean enabled = true;

    public static final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String surname;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String password;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: you are using the correct annotations? I.e. `javax.persistence.Entity`for spring-boot `< 6` and `jakarta.persistence.Entity` for spring-boot `>= 6`?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Turing85, I found a solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of javax dependency. I removed both dependency and code level lines from model.

Than I got an error:

```
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder and org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager
```

When I removed following dependency, error was also gone and all works fine now:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.